# why my python in visual studio code give me error

Tags: python

when ever I run this code its give me this error please help me is my code is wrong???

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('C:\akan\Hp\Documents\bird-in-tree\play.mp3')
```

Comment: it should be `/` instead of `\ `

Answer (score 0):

in python '\' is used as an escape character meaning that it and the following character are not treated as text but as code such as with the newline character \n
to use a '\' in a string you need to use '\\' or in this case the best option is to use '/'